# R : convert discrete column into matrix of logical values

Tags: r, matrix, machine-learning

I want to convert a discrete (identifier) variable into a series of logical columns so that I can use the variable as a feature in a Logistic Regression function (and others) where I can't mix continuous and discrete values.

I have a factor column in a data frame, and I want to convert the column into a matrix of columns (1.."number of levels") of logical values, for example:

```
my_labels=c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
my_tally=c(1,1,3,2,3,4,5,1)
my_tally=factor(my_tally, levels=c(1:6), labels=my_labels)
summary(my_tally)

expected_output=c(1,0,0,0,0,0,     #1
                  1,0,0,0,0,0,     #1
                  0,0,1,0,0,0,     #3
                  0,1,0,0,0,0,     #2
                  0,0,1,0,0,0,     #3
                  0,0,0,1,0,0,     #4
                  0,0,0,0,1,0,     #5
                  1,0,0,0,0,0      #1
                  )

expected_output=matrix(expected_output, 
                       nrow=length(my_tally), 
                       ncol=length(levels(my_tally)),
                       byrow=TRUE
                       )

expected_output
colSums(expected_output)
```

Any suggestions for a "fast" function to produce expected_output?  This is a large data problem (700 discrete possibilities, 1M observations).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are 2 solutions, one using base R, which will be faster on smaller data sets, and one using a sparse matrix from the `Matrix` package, which will be very fast on larger data sets.

Create the matrix filled with only 0's

```
mat <- matrix(0, nrow=length(my_tally), ncol=length(levels(my_tally)))
```

Use indices to assign 1's where appropriate:

```
mat[cbind(1:length(my_tally), as.numeric(my_tally))] <- 1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    1    0    0    0    0
#[5,]    0    0    1    0    0    0
#[6,]    0    0    0    1    0    0
#[7,]    0    0    0    0    1    0
#[8,]    1    0    0    0    0    0

colSums(mat)
#[1] 3 1 2 1 1 0
```

#### Approach # 2: Sparse Matrix

```
library(Matrix)
colSums(sparseMatrix(i=1:length(my_tally), j=as.numeric(my_tally),
    dims=c(length(my_tally), length(levels(my_tally)))))
#[1] 3 1 2 1 1 0
```

Here are some benchmarks on a larger sample data set (260 levels, 100,000 elements), where you can really see the benefit of using a sparse matrix:

```
# Sample data
my_labels <- c(LETTERS, letters, paste0(LETTERS, letters), paste0(letters, LETTERS),
            paste0(letters, letters, letters), paste0(LETTERS, LETTERS, LETTERS),
            paste0(LETTERS, letters, LETTERS), paste0(letters, LETTERS, letters),
            paste0(LETTERS, letters, letters), paste0(letters, LETTERS, LETTERS))
my_tally <- sample(1:260, 100000, replace=TRUE)
my_tally <- factor(my_tally, levels=c(1:260), labels=my_labels)

# Benchmarks
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  Robert <- colSums(table(1:length(my_tally),my_tally)),
  Frank1 <- {mat <- matrix(0, nrow=length(my_tally), ncol=length(levels(my_tally)))
      mat[cbind(1:length(my_tally), as.numeric(my_tally))] <- 1
      colSums(mat)},
  Frank2 <- colSums(sparseMatrix(i=1:length(my_tally), j=as.numeric(my_tally),
      dims=c(length(my_tally), length(levels(my_tally))))),
  Khashaa <- colSums(diag(length(my_labels))[my_tally, ])
  )

                lq       mean     median         uq      max neval  cld
Robert  444.625026 486.130804 461.653480 548.755603 632.1418   100    d
Frank1  328.947431 358.538855 337.136012 360.727606 458.2305   100   c 
Frank2    4.241506   8.997434   4.354615   4.519896 135.3001   100 a   
Khashaa 224.675094 256.337639 237.905714 260.163725 375.5642   100  b
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
expected_output<-table(1:length(my_tally),my_tally)
expected_output
colSums(expected_output)

a b c d e f 
3 1 2 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relatively simple solution using an `apply` function:

```
updateOutput <- function(entry, classInput = my_tally){
  column <- as.numeric(classInput[entry])
  row <- rep(0, length(levels(classInput)))
  row[column] <- 1
  row

}

expected_output <- t(apply(matrix(1:length(my_tally)), 1, updateOutput))

expected_output
```